# Pandas Data Frame - Sum all the values in a previous column which match a specific condition and add it to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm probably missing something, but I was not able to find a solution for this.
Is there a way in python to add values to a new column which satisfy a certain condition.
In Excel I would apply the following formula in the new column and paste it below

```
=SUMIF(A1:C1, ">0")
```

| val1 | val2 | val3 | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0.7 | -0.9 | 1.2 |
| 0.3 | -0.7 |  | 0.3 |
| -0.5 | -0.7 | -0.9 | 0 |

Also in my extracts, there are a few blank values. Can you please help me understand what code should be written for this?

```
df['total'] = df[['A','B']].sum(axis=1).where(df['A'] > 0, 0)
```

I came across the above code, but it checks only one condition. What I need is a sum of all of those columns which match the given condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way, somewhat similar to `SUMIF`:

```
# this is the "IF"
is_positive = df.loc[:, "val1": "val3"] > 0

# this is selecting the parts where condition holds & sums
df["output"] = df.loc[:, "val1": "val3"][is_positive].sum(axis=1)
```

where `axis=1` in last line is to sum along rows,

to get

```
>>> df

   val1  val2  val3  output
0   0.5   0.7  -0.9     1.2
1   0.3  -0.7   NaN     0.3
2  -0.5  -0.7  -0.9     0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` can handle that quite out of the box, like that:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,.7,-.9],[0.3,-.7,None],[-0.5,-.7,-.9]], columns=['val1','val2','val3'])

df['output'] = df[df>0].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) before `sum`:

```
df['total'] = df[['val1','val2','val3']].clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)

#solution by Nk03 from comments
cols = ['val1','val2','val3']
df['total'] = df[cols].mask(df[cols]<0).sum(axis=1)
```

EDIT: For test another mask by another columns convert them to numpy array:

```
df['total'] = df.loc[:, "D":"F"].mask(df.loc[:, "A":"C"].to_numpy() == 'Y', 0).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks!
How would you tweak this for finding <0.
Also, is there a general syntax for multiple conditions such as the one in SUMIF, say I wanted to have a string match of 'Y' on adjacent columns.
Example =SUMIF(A1:C1, "Y", D1:F1) Basically this means to sum values in D1, E1 and F1 if corresponding values (A1, B1, C1) are Y.
Sorry if this is tricky. Coming from an Excel background so understand it the best in that context. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way:

```
df["total"] = df.apply(lambda x: sum(x), axis=1).where((df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] > 0) & (another_condition) & (another_condition), 0)
```

Note the code will take sum across all columns at once. 
For taking sum of specific columns you can do the following:

```
df['total'] = df[['A','B','C','D','E']].sum(axis=1).where((df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] > 0) & (another_condition) & (another_condition), 0)
```